# template argument deduction for constructors

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, c++11, type-inference

Does C++0x have (or was C++0x at some point in time going to have) template argument deduction for constructors? In [An Overview of the Coming C++ (C++0x) Standard](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JffvCivHEHU), I saw the following lines:

```
std::lock_guard l(m);   // at 7:00

std::thread t(f);       // at 9:00
```

Does this mean that delegating `make_foo` function templates are finally redundant?

Comment: Oh wait, I think I confused constructors of class templates with constructor templates of classes... still an interesting question, methinks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Template argument deduction works for any function, including the constructor. But you can't deduce the class template parameters from arguments passed to the constructor. And no, you can't do it in 
C++0x either.

```
struct X
{
    template <class T> X(T x) {}
};

template <class T>
struct Y
{
    Y(T y) {} 
};

int main()
{
   X x(3); //T is deduced to be int. OK in C++03 and C++0x; 
   Y y(3); //compiler error: missing template argument list. Error in 03 and 0x
}
```

`lock_guard` and `thread` aren't class templates. They have constructor templates though.

Comment: Your post was in 2011, but to update a bit the C++1y should have it soon : http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3836.html look at paper N3602 on the page (http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3602.html).